# Node.js Express Middleware Error Chain

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

I have to scrape a web page for a key to use later as a cookie. That part works. But because the request is async the error is not handled. I want to make sure the error is passed along the middleware chain. But I can't get my brain around this one. Thanks for helping.

```
app.use('/', makeLoginCookie, function (req, res, next){
    console.log('My app.use() starts here.');
    //console.log('makeLoginCookie: %s', err);
    next(); 
});
```

And here's the function

```
function makeLoginCookie(req, res, next) {
    httpOptions = {
        url: site.url,
        headers: {
            Cookie: null
        }
    }

// Get HIDDEN key, build login cookie
request(httpOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        //console.log(body)
        var match = body.match( /\<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN id=\"key\", value=\"([0-9a-f]+)\"\>/i );
        var key = match[1]
        var encrypted = sha1(key + site.username + site.password);
        loginCookie = "username=" + key + ";password=" + encrypted;
        next();
    } else {
        console.log("Connect failed %s" , error);
        //err = new Error("Can't connect");
        next();
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to [Express Error handling](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html), you can use `next(err);` to pass error in `Express`. [Here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/12/error-handling-express-js-applications/) is one good link.

Comment: The problem I having is more complicated that `next(err)` and I tried and commented that as shown in my initial post. Look again at my `app.use()` and notice how `makeLoginCookie` is placed. That fixes my async problem but seems to break error handling. @Renan

Comment: Why is it more complicated? Call `next(error)` when an error occurs in `makeLoginCookie()`.

Comment: For some reason my application just locks up when I do that. I have the normal error handling provided by Express and I would expect it to fall thru the stack and give a 500 error. But it gets stuck somewhere. Any ideas how to trace there it's stuck?

Comment: Don't know why but I put `err = new Error("Can't connect"); next(err);` back in and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [promises (Q library)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) in order to resolve this, and for another things too, specially for web scraping. Your "makeLoginCookie" function could return a deferred.promise and, when the request fails, reject it with the error.

Edit 1: I recommend this great video that explains how to work properly with async code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obaSQBBWZLk. It could help you with this and another stuff.

Edit 2: Using promises would be like this, see if it helps you:

```
var Q = require("q");

app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {

    // This part, we will call your function "makeLoginCookie"
    makeLoginCookie().then(function(){
        // This is called when your function RESOLVES the promise

        // Here you could log or do some stuff...

        // Then, go next...
        next();
    }, function(error){
        // This is called when your function REJECTS the promise
        console.log("Connect failed %s" , error);

        // And then, handle the error, like stopping the request and sending an error:
        res.status(400).json({errorMessage: error});
    })
}, function (req, res, next){
    console.log('My app.use() starts here.');
    next(); 
});

// Removed parameters from function
function makeLoginCookie() {
    // This is the object that will return a promise
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    httpOptions = {
        url: site.url,
        headers: {
            Cookie: null
        }
    }

    // Get HIDDEN key, build login cookie
    request(httpOptions, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            //console.log(body)
            var match = body.match( /\<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN id=\"key\", value=\"([0-9a-f]+)\"\>/i );
            var key = match[1]
            var encrypted = sha1(key + site.username + site.password);
            loginCookie = "username=" + key + ";password=" + encrypted;

            // Instead of using next(), RESOLVE your promise
            // next();
            deferred.resolve(); // You can pass some data into it..
        } else {

            // Instead of using next(), REJECT your promise
            // next();
            deferred.reject(error); // You can pass some data into it, like an error object or string...
        }
    });

    // Promise that something will be fulfilled or reject later
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: That video was excellent. Gives me pause to think about going back to my old php ways as js is driving me nuts.

Comment: Totally, that helped me a lot! I have edited my answer with an example using promises to resolve your question. See if it helps.

Comment: That's really interesting. I'll try that and mark the post answered when I get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There must have been some error elsewhere in my code because this works as expected now.

```
} else {
    console.log("Connect failed %s" , error);
    err = new Error("Can't connect");
    next(err);
}
```